# Запись файла в конкретную папку

Tags: php

Требуется создать файл, записать в него информацию и сохранить в конкретную папку.

В корне файл создается

```
$file = "$index.php";
if (!file_exists($file)){
  $fp = fopen("$file", "w");
  fwrite($fp, $text);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

В нужной мне папке - нет

```
$file = "/modules/erps/include/scripts/cron/$index.php";
if (!file_exists($file)){
  $fp = fopen("/modules/erps/include/scripts/cron/$file", "w");
  fwrite($fp, $text);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Не нужно было при открытии и создании прописывать полный путь, так как он уже записан в переменную `$file`

Корректное создание:

```
$file = "modules/erps/include/scripts/cron/$index.php";
if (!file_exists($file)){
  $fp = fopen("$file", "w");
  fwrite($fp, $text);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> $file = "/modules/erps/include/scripts/cron/$index.php";

первый слэш означает путь от корня, но в структуре modules не в корне, а в замулеванной папке

Comment: зарисованная папка - это и есть корень. если убрать первый слэш - не сохраняется все равно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так.

$file = "/modules/erps/include/scripts/cron/index.php";

if (!file_exists($file)){

$fp = fopen("/modules/erps/include/scripts/cron/index.php", "w");

fwrite($fp, $text);

fclose($fp);
}